# how to find an index of the found id in the array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, search

how can I return the index value of my array after searching.

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT id,userName,email FROM user ORDER BY id ASC");
$myArray=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $myArray[$row['eMail']]=$row;
}
```

I am getting email as GET variable and I need to search like that

```
$search = $_GET["eMail"];

if (isset($myArray[$search])) {
  echo $my_values[$search]; 
  $isEmailStored= 1; // **means that I have but in WHICH INDEX I need to find out that**
}
else {
$isEmailStored=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This array_search help you

```
//example
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
```

//your code

```
if ( array_search($search,$my_values ) {
  echo $my_values[$search]; 
  $isEmailStored= 1; // means that I have but in WHICH INDEX I need to find out that
}
```

Comment: it didn't work I solved the issue by using sql code instead of php array search. thanks for your help.